# Python: Setting an element of a Numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am a pretty new to python. I have created an empty matrix

```
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(n,n))
```

Now I can access each element using

```
a.item(i,j)
```

How do I set an index (i,j)?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here's how:

```
a[i,j] = x
```

Answer (score 11):

Or

```
a.itemset((i,j),x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
a[i,j]=5
```